# php how replace characters before and after special characters

Tags: php, string

I have a php string like:

```
$string = '1234532323%A73823823221A%221312373712';
```

the string has numbers and 2 special tags `(%A and A%)` to indicate the begin and the end of the special part, respectively.

My goal is to replace all "1" with "2", but not in the part of the string between %A and A%.

If I use `strtr(string,"1","2")` all 1 occurrences will be replaced.
Does anyone know how my goal can be achieved?

Special characters may appear several times inside the string.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your [mcve]. One approach would be to use regular expressions, which you should research a little. e.g.: https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/php-regular-expressions

Comment: Hi. I know only strtr(string,"1","2") but this function does not work as it replaces all "1".

Comment: Then you have to get to know more of the PHP API. Sounds like some reading and hacking is in your future. Search for "PHP regular expression" and go from there. Handy link: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by breaking them apart and replacing the strings. do look into `preg_*` to better solve all cases.

```
$a = "1234532323%A73823823221A%221312373712";
//explode to an array of 3 objects
$b = explode('%',$a);
//replace the numbers in the first and last object
$b[0] = strtr($b[0],"1","2");
$b[2] = strtr($b[2],"1","2") ;
//concatenate them again to get $a
$a = $b[0].$b[1].$b[2];

echo($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can use this algorithm

> note: it's not written in any programmation language

```
int test = 0;
for(int i=0;i<ch.length();i++){
  if(test!=1 && ch(i)!="%"){
   if(ch(i)==1)
    ch(i)=2;
  }else
  {
   test++;
  }
}
```

Sorry for the bad presentation..